# Unresolved Reference Warning in Docstring - Python 3.6 - Pycharm 17.1.4

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, documentation, pycharm

I received this warning from PyCharm about an unresolved reference.
Here's code that is structured similarly, and should receive a warning as well.

```
class Parent:
    """
    === Attributes ===
    @type public_attribute_1: str
    """

    def __init__(self):
        public_attribute_1 = ''
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    """
    === Attributes ===
    @type public_attribute_1: str
        > Unresolved reference 'public_attribute_1'
    @type public_attribute_2: str
    """

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
        public_attribute_2 = ''

    pass
```

I understand that `public_attribute_1` is not explicitly initiated in `Child.__init__()`, but `Child.__init__()` calls `Parent.__init__(self)` which initiates `public_attribute_1`. Thus the error raised concerns readability and documentation more than functionality.

How can I make such code more readable, without inserting redundancies, thereby defeating the whole point of inheritance? 
Would it be sufficient to document thoroughly via docstrings and comments, and just ignore the warning from PyCharm? Or is there a pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: What's with the floating `pass`es? Also you should use `super().__init__()`.

Comment: I used `pass` because the rest of the code in these classes aren't important. I guess they're not really necessary but yeh.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues here.

1. In `Python 3` use `super()`
2. You are calling them "attributes", but this isn't how attributes work in Python. Glossing over details, use `self`.

Your question seems to be in regards to you want the `docstring` of `Child` to have all the attributes of `Parent` re-defined. This is pretty dangerous from a maintainability perspective though if anything ever changes. When I see a class inherits `Parent`, if I'm not familiar with `Parent`, I will go to the definition of `Parent` (which `PyCharm` makes easy with `Ctrl + B`).

I'll let someone else say if that's truly `pythonic`, but that's the way I'm used to working. Regardless, to fix your inheritance, your code should look more like this:

```
class Parent:
    """
    === Attributes ===
    @type public_attribute_1: str
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.public_attribute_1 = ''


class Child(Parent):
    """
    === Attributes ===
    @type public_attribute_2: str
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.public_attribute_2 = ''
        print(self.public_attribute_1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Could I ask the difference between `Parent.__init__(self)` and `super.__init__()`? I learned python through a course and I was taught inheritance by using `Parent.__init__(self)`, and the course was for Python 3.